# OneNote on SharePoint REST API

Tags: rest, sharepoint, onenote

The OneNote team recently [published a blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/onenotedev/archive/2015/06/11/and-sharepoint-makes-three.aspx) in which they explain how to access data from OneNote notebooks that are stored on SharePoint ('site-hosted notebooks', as they refer to them).

I'm trying to use the API as they describe it, but I'm unable to get it to work. Specifically, the first step is to find out my site collections and site ID using the following API call:

`https://www.onenote.com/api/beta/myorganization/siteCollections/FromUrl(url='{full-path-to-SharePoint-site}')`

It seems to fail no matter what I do: I tried to put the full path to my SharePoint site with and without 'http://' or 'https://', tried to write my organization name in various ways (with '-my' at the end, and without it), and probably a few other combinations as well - it just doesn't work. I keep getting error 400 / bad request.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "It just doesn't work" isn't that helpful. Surely, you must get a response from the server? What does it say?

Comment: You're right - I should have been more specific. Apologize for that. In any case, I'm getting 400 / Bad request, with no content in the response.

Comment: Can you send me the complete response headers for a call that fails please?  (garethj at microsoft dot com)  if you're able to send a complete decoded request/response pair captured using Fiddler as a .saz file, even better and we'll get an engineer to look at what is happening and raise an issue to give a better error.  Also will reply then answer to the thread with what was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So ... I had a fairly long correspondence with the guys from Microsoft, and here's what I learned:

- If you're using a browser or a browser plug-in to test some of your REST APIs calls, it's not enough to be logged-in as the relevant user. This works for SharePoint and other Office 365 APIs, but not for this OneNote API. You **must** send "Authorization: Bearer ... " in the request headers.
- Probably my stupid mistake, but 'myorganization' in the URL `https://www.onenote.com/api/beta/myorganization/siteCollections/FromUrl(url='{full-path-to-SharePoint-site}')` is **not** the name of your organization / domain: it's the literal string 'myorganization'.
- Finally, the 'full-path-to-sharepoint-site' should point to https://xyz.sharepoint.com and not to https://xyz-my.sharepoint.com.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax works like a charm for me:
https://www.onenote.com/api/beta/myorganization/siteCollections/FromUrl(url='https://XYZ.sharepoint.com/sites/ala')